# populate a variable with 3 possible strings based on multiple observations from multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to achieve this using the following data and code:

```
beg.new <-c(1,  0, 0,   0,  2,  3,  3)
GasBubbles<-c(0,    0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2)
PF<-    c(0,    0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0)
debris<-c(0, 1, 0,  0,  0,  1,  0)
diveLocation<-c('Compliance',   'Compliance',   'Compliance',   'Lease',     
'Lease',    'Lease',    'Lease')
nonComp<-   NA
nonCompLease<-  NA

df=data.frame(beg.new,  GasBubbles, PF, debris,     diveLocation,   nonComp,     
nonCompLease)
```

Giving the dataframe:

```
structure(list(beg.new = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3), GasBubbles = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2), PF = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), debris = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), diveLocation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Compliance", "Lease"), class = "factor"), 
nonComp = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), nonCompLease = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I want to populate the last two variables (nonComp and nonCompLease) depending on 'diveLocation' (if diveLocation = 'Compliance' then those rows and similarly if diveLocation = 'Lease' then those rows) and the observations of other variables. I have tried the folowing code:

```
#first noncompliance where diveLocation=='Compliance'
df$nonComp <- if(df$diveLocation=='Compliance' & df$beg.new==1& 
df$beg.new==2& df$beg.new==3& df$GasBubbles==1& df$GasBubbles==2& df$PF==1& 
df$PF==2& df$PF==3){
   print('yes')
}else{
  print('no')
}
```

and

```
#2nd noncompliance where diveLocation=='Lease'
df$nonCompLease <- ifelse(df$diveLocation=='Lease'& df$beg.new==3  & 
df$GasBubbles==2, df$PF==3, 'yes')
```

unfortunately I get:
nonComp = c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no")
nonCompLease = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "FALSE"))
whereas it should be:
nonComp = c("yes", "no", "no", NA, NA, NA, NA)
nonCompLease = c(NA, NA, NA, "no", "no", "yes", "yes"))

Any help with coding to get the desired result would be much appreciated

Comment: would you like to clarify your conditions to get your desired results? Right now it is not clear on what basis you want the output to be `yes`, `no` or `NA`

Comment: if noncompliance where diveLocation=='Compliance' and & df$beg.new==1 & df$beg.new==2& df$beg.new==3 & df$GasBubbles==1 & df$GasBubbles==2 & df$PF==1 & df$PF==2& df$PF==3) then df$nonComp gets 'yes' and if not df$nonComp gets 'no'

also

 if noncompliance where diveLocation=='Lease' and & df$beg.new==3  & df$GasBubbles==2 & df$PF==3,
df$nonCompLease gets 'yes' and if not df$nonCompLease gets 'no'

also

in some instances NA will be appropriate

Comment: That wasn't very clear at all. Can you put that in a table or something?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't very clear and @RonakShah

Comment: 1 Populate ‘nonComp’ variable with ‘yes’ based on.                   
 Variable Observation(s) a) diveLocation 'Compliance'. b) beg.new '1',  '2' or  '3'. c) GasBubbles '2'.  d) PF '1' , ' 2' or '3'.  However, if the observation does not equal that shown in b), c) or d) but does equal a) then ‘nonComp’ gets ‘no’. Further, if ‘diveLocation’ equals ‘Lease’ then ‘nonComp’ gets NA. @wl1234

Comment: 2 (also). Populate ‘nonCompLease’ variable with ‘yes’ based on. variable observations. e) diveLocation 'Lease'.  f) beg.new '3'.  g) GasBubbles '2'.  h) PF '3'.  However, if the observation does not equal that shown in f), g) and h) and does equal e) then ‘nonCompLease’ gets ‘no’. Further, if ‘diveLocation’ equals ‘Compliance’ then ‘nonCompLease’ gets NA. @wl1234 hopefully that clarifys. thanks for your help

Comment: So it has to meet all the conditions to be a yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised code which shows what you want it to:

```
    library(tidyverse)
df2 <- as_tibble(df)

df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(nonComp = case_when(diveLocation == "Compliance" & (beg.new %in% c(1, 2, 3) | GasBubbles == 2 | PF %in% c(1, 2, 3)) ~ "Yes",
                             diveLocation == "Lease" ~ NA_character_,
                             TRUE ~ "No")) %>% 
  mutate(nonCompLease = case_when(diveLocation == "Lease" & (beg.new == 3 | GasBubbles == 2 | PF == 3) ~ "Yes",
                                  diveLocation == "Compliance" ~ NA_character_,
                                  TRUE ~ "No"))
```

And df3 is:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 7
  beg.new GasBubbles    PF debris diveLocation nonComp nonCompLease
    <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>        <chr>   <chr>       
1       1          0     0      0 Compliance   Yes     NA          
2       0          0     0      1 Compliance   No      NA          
3       0          0     0      0 Compliance   No      NA          
4       0          0     1      0 Lease        NA      No          
5       2          0     1      0 Lease        NA      No          
6       3          1     0      1 Lease        NA      Yes         
7       3          2     0      0 Lease        NA      Yes
```

Comment: sorry it wasn't clearer to be yes it only has to meet the diveLocation and one of the key variables e.g. beg.new. I suppose I want something that gives &/or e.g. between GasBubblea and PF. Cheers